# Conformal map from open unit disc to right half plane while specifying behavior of semicircle

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I am hoping to find a conformal map sending the unit disc to $\mathrm{Re} z>0$ such that the upper semicircle is mapped to  $\{|z|\leq 1\mid \mathrm{Re} z>0\}$. Is this possible? I know of the $\frac{z+1}{1-z}$ one but it maps semicircles to one-fourth-planes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $\frac{i-z}{i+z}$ maps the unit disc to $\operatorname{Re }z>0$ and the upper semicircle to $\{|z|\le 1, \operatorname{Re }z>0\}.$